# Making a "Streak" Counter

Tags: java

I am creating a method that takes in an array of letters, "H" or "T". I need to return an int that represents the longest streak of "H" or "T" (which ever is longer).

```
Ex). streak({"H", "H", "T","H", "H", "H", "T", "T"});
```

Output: 3 since there are 3 "H"s in a row

Here is what I have so far:

```
public int streak(String[] arr) {
    int hCount = 0;
    int tCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        if (arr[i].equals("H") && !arr[i + 1].equals("T")) {
            hCount++;
        }
        if (arr[i].equals("T") && !arr[i + 1].equals("H")) {
            tCount++;
        }
    }
    return Math.max(hCount, tCount);
}
```

It works for a few test cases but not for

```
streak(new String[]{"T", "H", "T", "H", "T", "H", "T", "H"}) (expect 1)  or 

streak(new String[]{"T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T"}) (expect 8)
```

I am not allowed to change the method parameters.

Comment: You should reset tCount and hCount once the "streak" ends. Try a boolean flag to check if you're currently in a "T" streak or an "H" streak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Proposal

The easiest way is to reset `second` counter, when match condition for `first` counter;

So when `letter == "T"` just incremect `tCount` and reset `hCount`,
but when `letter == "H"` just incremect `hCount` and reset `tCount`,

This is the simplest and clearest solution without any additional conditions. You are adding one more counter `maxLength` and thats.

What's more, this solution can be modified to work for more letters.

## Code

Condition inside your method you can modify like explained:

```
if (letter.equals("T")) {
    tCount++;
    hCount = 0;
} else if (letter.equals("H")) {
    hCount++;
    tCount = 0;
}
```

And at the end of every loop you can check which of the counters has the biggest value:

```
maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, Math.max(hCount, tCount));
```

## Full solution

```
public int streak(String[] arr) {
    int maxLength = 0;
    int hCount = 0;
    int tCount = 0;

    for (String letter : arr) {
        if (letter.equals("T")) {
            tCount++;
            hCount = 0;
        } else if (letter.equals("H")) {
            hCount++;
            tCount = 0;
        }

        maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, Math.max(hCount, tCount));
    }

    return maxLength;
}
```